# How to reuse almost the same code between projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I'm trying to implement a report that is based on a web page.  The web page is in one project MyProject.Web, and the report is in MyProject.Reports project.  In both cases I want to display the same control element (a third-party chart control).  The Reports project uses a slightly different implementation (meaning most all the members are compatible) of the third-party chart control.  Almost all of the code can be copy-pasted between the two projects.  However, the following code is not compatible in the Reports project:

```
chart.BorderOptions.Visible = false; // BorderOptions is not a member
```

needs to be replaced with:

```
chart.Borders = BorderSide.None;
```

This:

```
chart.Height = Unit.Pixel(300); // Unit type
chart.Width = Unit.Pixel(700); // Unit type
```

needs to be replaced with:

```
chart.Height = 300; // int type 
chart.Width = 700; // int type
```

and finally:

```
chart.Padding.All = 0;
```

needs to be removed.

What's best solution here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a classic case of the [adapter pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx).

Basically, you can encapsulate the pieces that are different and only implement them differently. You could either create a `MyAwesomeChart` class and subclass that or something more like `MyAwesomeChartSetter`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the best solution would be to use the same implementation in both projects.

If you can't do that, then just leave it. If you posted all of the code, then it isn't actually that similar.

Comment: Ya, not able to do that since it's the third party that controls both implementations.  This is about one to two percent of the total code that is incompatible.  Everything else works fine.